# How to enter text in input field in iframe with multiple iframes on the same page in Cypress test?

Tags: iframe, cypress

I am trying to enter text in the highlighted input field inside an iframe in the below image (`id = 'encryptedCardNumber'`).

Also, there are multiple iframes on this page, so I need to somehow specify the one in the below image.

I tried the below test code, but the element wasn't found.

```
cy.get('iframe').then($element => {
    const $body = $element.contents().find('body')
    let body = cy.wrap($body)
    body.get('#encryptedCardNumber')
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your image but you should get the iframe with the id like this `cy.get('iframe #encryptedCardNumber')` assuming the the html looks smth like this: `<iframe id=encryptedCardNumber>`.

For only searching elements inside of this iFrame the `.within()` operator is very helpful.

```
cy.get('iframe #encryptedCardNumber').within(() => {
    cy.get('input[formcontrolname=\'username\']').type('whatYouWantToType')
})
```

This looks for an input inside of the iframe with the attribute formcontrollname='username' .

Answer (score 0):

Cypress doesn't work with iframes very well. You'll have to write some custom code or use the cypress-iframe plugin for instance. The following articles might be helpfull:

- https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress
- https://www.mariedrake.com/post/testing-iframes-with-cypress

Answer (score 0):

use 'cypress-iframe' js and then
cy.get(
".iframeparentDivClassname"
).within(($ifr) => {
cy.enter(".iframeClassname").then((getBody) => {
getBody().find("#encryptedCardNumber").type("123");
});
});